# 500 error posting via curl

Tags: json, curl

I am getting 500 error on posting the results via curl

```
curl -X PUT "http://xyz:8080/v1/test/086517a8-df1a-47a7-bcc7-056b08bd76d4/8911257e-7d7d-11e3-a26e-1e7184f6365b" -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{ "link":"http://xyz12.com/test.txt",    "environment":"QA",    "subtype":"ui",    "tests": [        {            "name": "lookup",            "passed": "17",            "failed": 0,            "skipped": 0        }    ],    "buildNumber":"7.0.0.1192",    "type":"functional"}'}'
```

I have validated the json string through json validator. The response I am getting is :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /v1/test/086517a8-df1a-47a7-bcc7-056b08bd76d4/8911257e-7d7d                                                                                                                                                             -11e3-a26e-1e7184f6365b. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>

</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is in the server "xyz:8080" (read what is said in the <title> tag) not with your curl

Comment: But i am successfully able to get response from the server using curl -X GET "http://xyz:8080/v1/test/086517a8-df1a-47a7-bcc7-056b08bd76d4/8911257e-7d7d-11e3-a26e-1e7184f6365b" The above results in 200 OK response

Comment: This is because server responded correctly to GET request, but there was a problem processing PUT - check your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be, your binding could be missing.

```
bind(Logic.class).to(LogicImpl.class)
```